# when using mysqli, does it make new connections every single time?

Tags: php, laravel

Let's say I'm using mysqli and pure php. I'm going to write pseudocode.

in config.php

```
$msql = new mysqli("username","password","dbname");
$msql->connect();
```

in app.php

```
include "config.php";

$row = mysqli_select("select * from posts");
foreach($row as $r){
 var_dump($r);
}
```

1) Question is : Everytime user makes a request or access the webpage on mywebsite.com/app.php, every time new mysql instance gets created and the old one gets destroyed? or there's only one mysql instance at all (one single connection to database)

Comment: Grep for "persistent connection" on the [documentation page](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php)

Answer (score 2):

Yes each time your script runs it will make a new connection to the database and a new request to retrieve data.

Even though you don't close the connection at the end of your script, the mysqli connection is destroyed at the end of it, so you can't "trick" it to stay open or work in a cookie-way let's say.

I mean it's what it is supposed a script to be doing. Connects to the db, does it's job, leaves the db (connection dies).

On the other hand if in the same script you have like 2-3 or more queries then it's another story because as i mentioned above the connection of mysqli dies at the end of the script, meaning that you make 1 connection, run all your script queries and you exit after.

***Edit for answering comment:***

Let's assume that i come into your page and a friend of mine comes at the same time (let's assume as i said). I connect in your database and request some data and so does a friend of mine. Let's see the procedure:

We both trigger a backend script to run for each of us. In this script an instance of mysqli is created so we have 2 instances running at this time but for two separate users.

And that makes total sense and let me elaborate on this:

Think of a page that you book your holidays. If i want to see ticket prices for France and you want to see ticket prices for England then in the php script that runs there is going to be put a where clause for each of us like :

`->where('destination','France');`

After that the data is send in the frontend and i am able to see what i requested. Meanwhile my instance is dead as i queried the database, got my result and there is nothing more to be done.

The same happens with every user who will join at this time. He/she will create his instance, get the data he wants to get and let his instance die.

***Latest edit:***

After reading your latest comment i figured out what was your issue first hand. So as i mentioned in my post an instance that a user created in mysqli can not be shared with any other user. It is build to be unique.

What you can do if you have that much traffic is that you cache your data. You can use Reddis database that is build specifically for that reason, to be queried a lot and you can set caching to it, so it deletes the data after some time if you want to.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but imagine situation when two requests come at the same time, what will happen then? Does it creates two connection instance for each request or something else happens?

Comment: Edited my answer to elaborate more. Hope it is more clear.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if There's one instance of mysqli class and everyone who connects uses this instance? this way if 100000 users use my website, there won't be 100000 instances of mysqli class and will be only 1 which is better because we don't have many resources allocated for instances.